# Trigger Logic Apps from Spfx extension for selected items

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, logic-app

Can we trigger logic app from extension click using spfx for selected items?
ex: if i select 5 items and click on SPFX extension in Sharepoint Logic app will trigger for all 5 items and send email to approver columns is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to trigger Logic app through SPfx extension. We can set a http trigger for the logic app then call it from SPFx. Below is a helpful blog, you can take a reference:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-call-azure-function/
- https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/05/call-azure-function-from-spfx-2.html

BR